# Is Wordpress the best tool to build an LMS social platform?

Tags: wordpress, canvas-lms

I'm trying to build an educational social platform with a lot of functionality in it, and i was wondering if Wordpress is the best choice for that?

Comment: Off-topic, opinion-based, and even if it wasn't, there's not enough information anyway. "Social platform" means nothing.

Comment: Well, i edited it, i mean an LMS platform, would wordpress be the best or like Ruby on rails for backend?

Comment: It'll always be off-topic. No clue what an LMS platform is.

Comment: Learning Management System

Comment: I see. Still OT, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress is the most popular CMS platform in the world and can easily be modified into a LMS platform.

However, the most popular and suggested "native" LMS platforms are [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) and [Talent LMS](https://www.talentlms.com/)

It is hard to tell which is the optimal for you since you haven't mentioned any requirements. I think you should compare the options of all the listed platforms and decide by yourself.

Comment: Would using Ruby and javascript to build one from scratch be better?, because i want to add a lot of features, that's not in any theme or platform i found.

Comment: Well that really depends on your knowledge/budget. If you have a large budget then it's better to build something from scratch as it will be exactly as you want it, in that case you can go with any CMS language you want (Ruby and Javascript or something else). On the other hand if you have a smaller budget/knowledge then you should go with some pre made CMS and add some modifications to it. Wordpress has got the largest community and most plugins, so in that case you should consider it or maybe Moodle.

Answer (score -1):

No wordpress is not a good for development for LMS.